# Can't use function from android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to use the function `AMotionEvent_getActionButton` from Android NDK

**But I get the following error**

```
C/C++: /usr/home/ndk-project/main.c:188:26: error: 'AMotionEvent_getActionButton' is unavailable: introduced in Android 33
C/C++: /usr/android-sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/android/input.h:1370:9: note: 'AMotionEvent_getActionButton' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
```

It says the function was introduced in Android 33
I am using Android 33

**The concerned line of code**

```
int32_t buttonPress = AMotionEvent_getActionButton(event);
```

**Module Level build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33
    ndkVersion '25.1.8937393'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 33
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86_64'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.example.app'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
}
```

Why I am I getting this error?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/sdk-versions#compilesdkversion):

> **compileSdkVersion**
>
> This property has no effect on NDK builds. API availability for the NDK is instead governed by `minSdkVersion`. This is because C++ symbols are eagerly resolved at library load time rather than lazily resolved when first called (as they are in Java). Using any symbols that are not available in the `minSdkVersion` will cause the library to fail to load on OS versions that do not have the newer API, regardless of whether or not those APIs will be called.

Comment: Just keep in mind that people with Android versions older than 13 (SDK version 33) won't be able to install your app if you do this. So you'll have to decide whether having access to `AMotionEvent_getActionButton` is worth that trade-off.